# Junit test that persist in mysql

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, junit4

Is it possible to write junit test that persist in mysql using hibernate / jpa?

If so any example available?
I'm using spring/hibernate for my application

Answer (score 0):

When you have real database connection I would not call your test `unit test`, but more like `integration test`. To be honest this kind of tests is not a good idea in most cases. It requires some maintenance (every time you have changes in db), and in most cases just tests if it is possible to connect do database (and save some simple object).

Focus on writing good tests for domain level classes. Simple database integration tests will only give you illusion of high quality application.

Comment: Actually i have an android device that am using to communicate with my server via webservice. So am dependent on the android to test if my save method is working. That's why i want to write a junit for this method to see if it persist in db. My db is a test one. So i can do anything with it(delete/add) and it's a simple object that I'm saving

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write an integration test that looks like a unit test, you could try [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org).

What Arquillian does is basically start an application container (Glassfish I think is the default), then it deploys your server-side application in the container and runs the tests against the just-deployed application.

What you write in the unit tests is really client code, so that what you are effectively running is an integration test (with a real database and all the services you would have in a real environment), just in a junit-like way.

They also have a specific [tutorial](http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/) for persistence testing.